# Updating Core Data executes UITableView problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my app I have to update one attribute (boolean) when user tap on cell. In case like this I thought that everything should happen in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and I was able to partially do what I wanted but...

Here is some code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Group *selectedGroup = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    switch ([selectedGroup.selected boolValue]) {
        case 0:
            [selectedGroup setSelected:@YES];
            break;
        case 1:
            [selectedGroup setSelected:@NO];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.moc save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    // Hiding selection with animation for nice and clean effect
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

When user tap everything is saved like it should but after restart of application **I loose those selected objects**. They occur in strange places in `NSFetchedResultsController` when `fetchedObjects` method is called. Have a look on screenshot:

[image]

Those numbers are object id and this boolean value. Objects are sorted alphabetically and group with id 2 is called `{"id":2,"name":"AZS Aerobic I"}` but now it strangely transforms to **ZaN355A1** like on screen:

[image]

And this group has id `{"id":2911,"name":"ZaN355A1"}`.
**I guess everything is happening because of `indexPath` which is the source of object position in table view** but I don't know how solve this and keep objects in proper order in table view.

Comment: Do you also pass the other UITableViewDataSource method calls properly to the fetched results controller?

Comment: @Lightforce I think yes. I thought of getting staright to the object, not by using `indexPath` (and have no idea how to do that) but on the other hand...